# How can I run my Selenium Headerless, in Python

Tags: python

I am having the worlds hardest time getting my Python Code to run headerless.. here's what I've done.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

That's included at the top of my script, then I've included this.

```
def login(self, username, password):
    self.destroyDriver()
    try:

        print(("Logging into => ", username))
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.get("https://example.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("sign-in").click()
        time.sleep(6)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("avatarname").send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary").click()
        time.sleep(4)
        if "welcome/login" in self.driver.current_url:
            self.destroyDriver()
            return False
    except:
        self.destroyDriver()
        return 17
    return True
```

However, this doesn't work at all the Chrome tab still pops up. I am trying to run headerless because when the tab is minimized on my desktop the Javascript does not load properly, and causes the entire script to break forcing me to keep the tab constantly open.

Answer (score 0):

you have to attach your option into your driver

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Upon adding this into my code the .py file just instantly closes. Same issue I had before also.

Comment: try to disable the `try except` and let it log the error

Comment: Try changing the `options` in `webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)` to `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`